# What user-information is available to code running in browsers?

Tags: browser, web, sandbox

I recently had an argument with someone regarding the ability of a website to take screenshots on the user's machine. He argued that using a GUI-program to simulate clicking a mouse really fast to win a simple flash game could theoretically be detected (if the site cared enough) by logging abnormally high scores and taking a screenshot of those players' desktops for moderator review. I argued that since all website code runs within the browser, it cannot step outside the system to take such a screenshot.

This segued into a more general discussion of the capabilities of websites, through Javascript, Flash, or whatever other method (acceptable or nefarious), to make that step outside of the system. We agreed that at minimum some things were grabbable: the OS, the size of the user's full desktop. But we definitely couldn't agree on how sandboxed in-browser code was. All in all he gave website code way more credit than I did.

So, who's right? Can websites take desktop screenshots? Can they enumerate all your open windows? What else can (or can't) they do? Clearly any such code would have to be OS-specific, but imagine an ambitious site willing to write the code to target multiple OSes and systems.

Googling this led me to many red herrings with relatively little good information, so I decided to ask here

Comment: Browser plugins != in-browser code

Comment: Hmm true, scratch that, edited. Rest of the question still stands though.

Comment: Oh, except for some reason I was thinking Flash isn't a plugin. Well, I am still interested in Flash's capabilities since it's a sandbox of its own in a sense, in which websites can only do what the Flash language lets them. And I have no practical Flash experience to know the limits of those capabilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, the security model of browsers is supposed to keep javascript code completely contained within its sandbox. Anything about the local machine that isn't reflected in the properties of the window object and its children is inaccessible.

Plugins, on the other hand, have free reign. They're installed by the user, and can access anything the user can access. That's why they're able to access your webcam, upload files, do virus scans, etc. They're also able to expose APIs to javascript code, which pokes a hole in the javascript sandbox and gives javascript code some external access. That's how tools like Phonegap give javascript code in web apps access to phone hardware (gps, orientation, camera, etc.)

Comment: Interesting, so since Flash is a plugin, Flash games and other content have user-level access. But the Flash language itself would have to give the user-environment snooping capabilities to websites since they would have to run in THAT sandbox. Something like that?

Comment: That's right. I know that the Flash supports uploading files and is able to show upload progress, which implies the ability to do block-by-block file IO. With that capability, Flash can probably access anything it needs to get info from the machine. Maybe not screenshots though, at least not without the user's permission.